# Why can't I pass stdout from netcat to awk?

Tags: bash, awk, raspbian, netcat

I'm using Raspbian (actually it's HASSBian) on a RPi3.  I'm trying to parse output from netcat:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ netcat localhost 1099 | grep -i on
01/01 22:57:29 Rx RF HouseUnit: C2 Func: On
01/01 22:57:30 Rx RF HouseUnit: B4 Func: On
01/01 22:57:31 Rx RF HouseUnit: B5 Func: On
01/01 22:57:32 Rx RF HouseUnit: B6 Func: On
01/01 22:57:40 Rx RF HouseUnit: C1 Func: On
01/01 22:57:47 Rx RF HouseUnit: C2 Func: On
01/01 22:58:03 Rx RF HouseUnit: C2 Func: On
01/01 22:58:04 Rx RF HouseUnit: C1 Func: On
```

but when I try to pipe this to awk to pull out the two fields I want I get no output.  It looks like this:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ netcat localhost 1099 | grep -i on | awk '{print $6,$8}'
```

Am I wrong in thinking that this should just work?

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 4.4.38-v7+ #938 SMP Thu Dec 15 15:22:21 GMT 2016 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 2):

The output of grep is fully buffered when not writing to a terminal. Use the `--line-buffered` flag for grep

```
netcat localhost 1099 | grep --line-buffered -i on | awk '{print $6,$8}'
```

For programs that does not allow you to control its output buffering behavior, it the program can be wrapped with the [stdbuf](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/stdbuf-invocation.html) command

Comment: Why not suggest to not use `grep` and use only `awk`? come on, make an effort!

Comment: Why not suggest that yourself as an answer?

Comment: Because it would be too much noise to add another answer for such a trivial question.

Comment: Sorry guys.. no matter what I do cannot get output from awk. I get output with:

netcat localhost 1099 | grep --line-buffered -i on

but not with:

netcat localhost 1099 | grep --line-buffered -i on | awk '{print $6,$8}'

Comment: Further,  netcat localhost 1099 | awk '{print $6,$8}'  does not give any output either.  I don't actually need the grep, but awk is required.  Frustrating.